# Is there a way to create an object in an if statement but make sure that it destructs afterwards?

Tags: c++

I have an object that has a bool operator override:

```cpp
class Table {
public:
  Table(const char *id) { mOpen = true; std::cout << "Opened\n"; }
  ~Table() {
    if (mOpen) {
      std::cout << "Closed\n";
    }
  }

  inline operator bool() const { return mOpen; }

private:
  bool mOpen = false;
};
```

This allows me to use this object as a function where cleanup happens after the scope is finished:

```cpp
if (auto table = Table("TestTable")) {
  std::cout << "Inside the table\n";
}

// Opened
// Inside the table
// Closed
```

I have other types of classes similar to this where most of the time, the assignment is not necessary. Let's use the same table as an example:

```cpp
if (Table("TestTable")) {
  std::cout << "Inside the table\n";
}

// Opened
// Closed
// Inside the table
```

In order to solve this, I am always assigning a value to this:

```cpp
if (auto _ = Table("TestTable")) {
  std::cout << "Inside the table\n";
}

// Opened
// Inside the table
// Closed
```

I understand that the temporary variable can be used inside the body of the `if` statement; therefore, the destructor is not called until the scope is closed. In the case of no assignment, there is no variable; so, it gets destroyed within the condition itself.

I would like to know if there is any way in C++ to make the non assigned use-case to destruct after the scope is finished?

Comment: No, there is no way. You could replace `if` with a function that takes a lambda and runs it with a condition, but I like the `if` more.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (auto _ = Table("TestTable"))`? Since C++17 this has the same performance as `if (Table("TestTable"))`

Comment: This have the smell of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the original problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need the object to stay alive until the end of the full `if` statement? Why don't you want to store the object in a variable for that?

Comment: Alternatively, in C++17 and later, `if (auto _ = Table("TestTable")) { ... }` can be re-written as `if (Table _("TestTable"); _) { ... }` which is functionally equivalent to simply wrapping the `if` inside a block scope and moving the declaration above the `if`, eg: `{ Table _("TestTable"); if (_) { ... } }`

Comment: @NathanOliver there is nothing wrong in doing one or the other but it would be nice if I did not have to provide the variable. For this particular part of my problem, I do not care much about the performance. The main thing I care about is API design.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using a UI library that I really like working with but due to its low level, which makes it error prone. For example, a `BeginTable` function needs to be closed with `EndTable` or the whole application crashes. So, I want to use RAII where the ctor is begin and dtor is end. I can of course create an object and the check the if condition to know if I can draw inside of but if possible, I want to also eliminate the code bloat by creating objects, needing to name them etc. My question is more about how I want to design and use my APIs.

Comment: @Gasim I'm not sure how you would use a table without having a name to it.

Comment: @appleapple I gave a bad example. Table one actually works exactly as I like but there are other widgets such as Window, MainMenuBar, Section etc that have some APIs that make sense to use with but for the majority of use-cases, it is just about making sure that constructor and destructor are called in the defined order.

Comment: Well, maybe you could rewrite it using [a lambda](https://godbolt.org/z/nhaebao4a), if it makes sense in your use case.

Comment: Depending on your design and use-cases, perhaps you could wrap the widgets and use some sort of [method chaining](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#method-chaining) to perform your operations?

Comment: @Bob__ Your lambda solution is flawed. You are running the if statement body (`action_()` in your code) in a constructor, which should always be avoided. When resource allocation is finished, constructor should finish immediately. It should not do something unrelated like `action_()`. Think about it: if the code in `action_` throws, the constructor fails, and destructor will not be called, the resource is never released, leading to resource leak.

Comment: @RabidBear See e.g. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#ctors-can-throw and https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#selfcleaning-members and a more convoluted [snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/MaaEnxvoE).